# How to use group by and count in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I am having 3 table using I have to take the count

> trip_details

```
id    allocationId       tripId

1         7637             aIz2o
2         7626             osseC
3         7536             01LEC
4         7536             78w2w
5         7640             S60zF
6         7548             ruaoR
7         7548             Qse6s
```

> escort_allocation

```
id       allocationId    escortId

3          7637            1
4          7626            1
5          7627            1
6          7536            1
7          7640            1
7          7548            1
```

> cab_allocation

```
 allocationId    allocationType

 7637             Daily Trip
 7626             Daily Trip
 7627             Daily Trip
 7536              Adhoc Trip
 7640               Adhoc Trip
 7548               Daily Trip
```

Using above table I have to get the count, I tried but it is not happening my expected results.

**I tried sql query**

```
    SELECT a.`tripId` 
FROM  `trip_details` a
INNER JOIN escort_allocation b ON a.`allocationId` = b.`allocationId` 
GROUP BY a.`allocationId` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**I am getting like this**

```
tripId

01LEC
ruaoR
osseC
aIz2o
S60zF
```

`total 6 tripId i got` ,so now I want to take the count so I am using this query

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  `trip_details` a
INNER JOIN escort_allocation b ON a.`allocationId` = b.`allocationId` 
GROUP BY a.`allocationId` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but this query is not working.**I am getting results like below**

```
 2
2
1
1
1
```

> MY MYSQL TABLES AND VALUES LOOK LIKE THIS

```
    CREATE TABLE `trip_details` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `allocationId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tripId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `tripId` (`tripId`),
 KEY `allocationId` (`allocationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

INSERT INTO trip_details
    (id, allocationId, tripId)
VALUES
    (1, 7637, '00SwM'),
    (2, 7626, '00SwM'),
    (3, 7536, '00SwM'),
    (4, 7536, '01hEU'),
    (5, 7640, '01hEU'),
    (6, 7548, 'IRZMS'),
    (7, 7548, 'IRZMS');




CREATE TABLE `escort_allocation` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `allocationId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `escortId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

INSERT INTO escort_allocation
    (id, allocationId, escortId)
VALUES
    (1, 7637, 'ssda'),
    (2, 7626, 'adad'),
    (3, 7627, 'sfsaf'),
    (4, 7536, 'ssaf'),
    (5, 7640, 'asf'),
    (6, 7548, 'a3r');



CREATE TABLE `cab_allocation` (
 `allocationId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `allocationType` enum('Daily Trip','Adhoc Trip') NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`allocationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7695 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO cab_allocation
    (allocationId, allocationType)
VALUES
    (7637, 'Daily Trip'),
    (7626, 'Daily Trip'),
    (7627, 'Daily Trip'),
    (7536, 'Adhoc Trip'),
    (7640, 'Adhoc Trip'),
    (7548, 'Daily Trip');
```

Comment: The count of what?  Desired results would really help.

Comment: What is your desired output??

Comment: @ Rakibul Islam My out put should come `5`

Comment: @ Rakibul Islam `escort_allocation` table i am having total `6` allocationId but i am using INNER JOIN so result should come '5'

Comment: check out my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.allocationId)
FROM
trip_details a
INNER JOIN
escort_allocation b
ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId
```

Previously you used `COUNT(*)` and also used `GROUP BY` so the counts of rows you were getting are from individual groups.

**Update-2:**

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trip_details
) AS Total_Trip_Count,
COUNT(T.tripId) as Escort_Count,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (
        SELECT a.allocationId
        FROM escort_allocation a 
        INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON a.allocationId = c.allocationId 
        WHERE c.allocationType = 'Adhoc Trip' 
        GROUP BY a.allocationId
    ) AS Ad
) AS Adhoc_Trip_Count
FROM 
( 
    SELECT a.tripId FROM 
    trip_details a 
    INNER JOIN 
    escort_allocation b 
    ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
    GROUP BY a.allocationId 
) AS T
```

Comment: I tried this code **SELECT COUNT(T.tripId)  as Escort_Count
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.`tripId` 
    FROM  `trip_details` a
    INNER JOIN escort_allocation b ON a.`allocationId` = b.`allocationId` 
    GROUP BY a.`allocationId` 
) AS T** it is working

Comment: But again i have to join one more table 'cab_allocation' using allocation id and i have to take the count. howmany `allocationType` we are using `Adhoc Trip`

Comment: In that case you may use the 2nd part of my answer.....just replace the query within the first bracket with your new `select` and `inner join` query

Comment: i tried your code but i am getting error `Every derived table must have its own alias`,Kindly update your code like both count, 1.Escort_Count 2.Adhoc_Count

Comment: You need Escort_Count and Adhoc_Count by same query or by two diferent queries

Comment: i tried myself but i a m getting error **SELECT COUNT(T.tripId)  as Escort_Count,COUNT(c.`allocationId`) as Adhoc_Count
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.`tripId` 
    FROM  `trip_details` a
    INNER JOIN escort_allocation b ON a.`allocationId` = b.`allocationId` INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON c.`allocationId` = a.`allocationId` WHERE c.allocationType = 'Adhoc Trip'
    GROUP BY a.`allocationId` 
) AS T**   `ERROR = ` #1054 - Unknown column 'c.allocationId' in 'field list'

Comment: In same query i need

Comment: when you want to count Adhoc_trip as well, then what is your desired output for Escort_count, is it still 5 or 2 in this case???

Comment: My desired output is Escort_count `5` , Adhoc_trip `2`

Comment: I've updated my answer, plz take a look on that and tell me if it helps

Comment: I tried i am getting error `#1054 - Unknown column 'Ad.allocationId' in 'field list'`

Comment: Can you make please in SQL fiddle

Comment: I updated my question and also i given mysql tables and values,Kindly check this section `MY MYSQL TABLES AND VALUES LOOK LIKE THIS`

Comment: I made sql fiddle also see this link [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e34392/4)

Comment: Mr  Rakibul Islam ,You saw my fiddle,can you please update your answer

Comment: I am really very happy MR  Rakibul Islam

Comment: I am not able to upvote because i am having less reputation , when i will reach enough reputation sure i will make upvaote

Comment: I want to take one more count also like , total trip count , that means trip_details table how many rows present i want to take that also,kindly update your query

Comment: @Mr  Rakibul Islam , are you there, kindly update me please

Comment: well, updated and here's the sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e34392/54

Answer (score 1):

With this, you should get the tripid and the amount:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.tripId) as total, a.tripId as tripId 
FROM trip_details a INNER JOIN escort_allocation b 
ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
GROUP BY a.allocationId LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I am getting results like this `COUNT(a.tripId)
2
2
1
1
1
`

Comment: SELECT COUNT(a.tripId)  as total, a.tripId as tripId FROM  `trip_details` a
INNER JOIN escort_allocation b ON a.`allocationId` = b.`allocationId` 
GROUP BY a.`allocationId` 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (a.`tripId`))
 FROM  `trip_details` a
 INNER JOIN escort_allocation b ON a.`allocationId`=b.`allocationId`
 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

because of `GROUP BY` there is separate count for all **allocationId**.